# How to add this java script banner randomly load

Tags: javascript

$(document).omSlider({ slider: $('.slider'), dots: $('.dots'), next:$('.btn-right'), pre:$('.btn-left'), timer: 5000, showtime: 1500,

Comment: You should give more details.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).omSlider({
    slider: $('.slider'),
    dots: $('.dots'),
    next:$('.btn-right'),
    pre:$('.btn-left'),
    timer: 5000,
    showtime: 1500,
 });
  </script>

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please spend some time and visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/) to get accustomed to site. Refer [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's see;

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function getRandBetween(min, max) {
  return parseInt(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

setTimeout(function(){
    // Your code to trigger the banner function goes here.
    // Eg;
     $(document).omSlider({ slider: $('.slider'), dots: $('.dots'), next:$('.btn-right'), pre:$('.btn-left'), timer: 5000, showtime: 1500, });

},getRandBetween(0,20000));

        </script>
```

Here is a function that gets the random value between the values that you specify.

And we use this function to get a random time value to show or trigger your banner function with `setTimeout()` function.

Your banner will be triggered randomly between 0ms or 20secs, you can change this values.